# Is the participle tense time-neutral?

Tags: grammar, tense

Is the participle tense time-neutral? I am wondering if it's the case, because these two seem to be grammatically correct.

> She won the competition after **having sung** the national Anthem during
>   the finals.
>
> She won the competition after **singing** the national Anthem during the
>   finals.

Now, because I am not sure if the participle tense time-neutral, I am not sure if the last sentence is correct or not. Is it? Why? Also, why does it sound grammatically incorrect?

Comment: In both sentences you use *after*, clearly indicating a timeline. The *context* (as well as the past tense of *win*) is far from timeless. To me, I'm not sure how this is different than asking if *ball* is "time-neutral" in *she bounced the ball*. (A question I would similarly want to have clarified.)

Comment: You might say that the perfect is redundant since the anterior (past) meaning is conveyed by "after".

Comment: Weird, I would have thought "singing" was wrong and needs to be replaced "having sung". Did the rules change recently?

Comment: @yocu I have been saying things like that for a lifetime - and I am not young. What rules do you have in mind?

Comment: Time needs to be consistent with the tense. I have also heard people tell me to use the same tense in the same sentence in essays.